# Jquery not working in Windows8 HTML 5 App

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows-8

I created new Windows 8 HTML 5 App. I added jquery file to it. But the `Hello World!` is not getting printed in `TextBox`

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
private void Browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add your URL here
        Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
        Browser.Navigate(new Uri(MainUri, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/html/css/phone.css" />
    <title>Windows Phone</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function (){
            $("#test").val("Hello World!");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Climate</p>
    </div>
    <div id="page-title">
        <p>My Climate</p>
        <input type="text" id="test" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: define "doesn't work". Any error appeared in Developer Console ?

Comment: Thanks, hi i am new to windows 8 HTML 5 phone app. Where it will be ?

Comment: Can you run it in PC browser first? It is in your browser.

Comment: Jquery code is fine and there must be some issue in Windows 8 HTML 5 app. I am unable to trace it...

Comment: Could you launch it with debugger to see if some error will occur?

Comment: I just tested your code and it worked well. Have you checked the path to your jQuery file?

Comment: @Maffelu, yes its correct. Do the windows emulator have any dependancy ?

Comment: @outcoldman, hi i already in debug mode. How to launch it with debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that the "~/" in the script URI isn't interpreted correctly or the URI is otherwise incorrect. I know for a fact that jQuery works just fine in W8 apps.

Answer (score 0):

I would just move it to the route directory of your app, or reference the file relatively.